# Flutter bloc and Firebase phone auth

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

`enter code here`I'm trying to create a LoginBloc which uses Firebase phone authentication. I created a StreamController for phoneNumber, smsCode and for verificationId. I'd like to add their values in VerificationNumber() method dynamically with the help of Bloc pattern. This is the LoginBloc within the verificationNumber():

```
class LoginBloc extends Object with AuthValidator implements BlocBase {

  String _phone;
  String _sms;
  String _verifId;

  StreamController<String> _phoneController=StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  //Sink<String> get _addPhone=>_phoneController.sink;
  Stream<String> get getPhone=>_phoneController.stream.transform(validatePhone);

  StreamController<String> _codeController=StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  Stream<bool> get registerValid => Observable.combineLatest2(getPhone,getPhone
          ,(e, p) =>true);

  //Sink<String> get _addCode=>_phoneController.sink;
  Stream<String> get getCode=>_phoneController.stream.transform(validatePhone);
  Function(String) get onPhoneChanged => _phoneController.sink.add;

  StreamController<String> _verificationIdController=StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  Sink<String> get _addVerification=>_verificationIdController.sink;
  Stream<String> get getVerification=>_verificationIdController.stream;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _phoneController.close();
    _codeController.close();
    _verificationIdController.close();
  }

  Future<void> verifyPhone(String phone, String verifId,String sms) async {

    _phone=phone;
    _sms=sms;
    _verifId=verifId;

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve=(String verId) {
      _verifId=verId;
      _addVerification.add(_verifId);
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent=(String verId,[int forceCodeRetrieve]) {
      _verifId=verId;
      _addVerification.add(_verifId);
    };

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted phoneVerificationCompleted=(FirebaseUser user) {
      print("User $user");
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed phoneVerificationFailed=(AuthException exception) {
      print("Error $exception");
    };

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: _phone,
        timeout: Duration(minutes: 1),
        verificationCompleted: phoneVerificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: phoneVerificationFailed,
        codeSent: smsCodeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve);
  }
}

LoginBloc loginBloc=LoginBloc();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution with work for now:
this is the login_bloc:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:phone_auth_bloc/services/auth/authentification.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart';

class LoginBloc implements BlocBase {
  final Authentification _authentification = new Authentification();


  final _phoneControler = new BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Observable<String> get phoneStream => _phoneControler.stream;
  Sink<String> get phoneEvent => _phoneControler.sink;

  final _smsControler = new BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Observable<String> get smsStream => _phoneControler.stream;
  Sink<String> get smsEvent => _phoneControler.sink;

  var _controllerLoading = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(seedValue: false);

  Stream<bool> get outLoading => _controllerLoading.stream;

  final BuildContext context;
  LoginBloc(this.context);

   onClickPhone() async {
    print(_phoneControler.value);
    _controllerLoading.add(!_controllerLoading.value);

        await _authentification.verifyPhoneNumber(_phoneControler.value);
    _controllerLoading.add(!_controllerLoading.value);


  }

  Future<bool> onClickSms() async {
    print(_phoneControler.value);

    _controllerLoading.add(!_controllerLoading.value);
    bool isAuth = await _authentification.signWithPhone(
        _authentification?.verificationId, _smsControler.value);
    _controllerLoading.add(!_controllerLoading.value);
    print(isAuth);
    return isAuth;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerLoading?.close();
    _phoneControler?.close();
    _smsControler?.close();
  }
}
```

and the class witch communicate with:

```
class Authentification{
  final _firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.instance;
   String verificationId;

  Future<bool> signWithPhone(String verifiId,String smsCode) async{
    verificationId=verifiId;
    print(verificationId);
   final resultLogin=await _firebaseAuth.signInWithPhoneNumber(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
   if(resultLogin?.uid!=null){
      return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
  }

  Future verifyPhoneNumber(String phone)async{
    await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phone,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
        verificationCompleted: (FirebaseUser user){
          print("User: "+user?.uid);
        },
        verificationFailed: (AuthException authException){
          print("exception: $authException");
        },
        codeSent: (String verifId,[int forceSent]){
          print("verificannId: $verifId");
          verificationId=verifId;
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String timeOut){
          print("Time out: "+timeOut);
        });
  }
}
```

after that you can call the bloc in the Ui this is in my case:

```
class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthFormState createState() => _AuthFormState();
}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LoginBloc loginBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);

    navigateTOnext(){
      loginBloc.onClickPhone().then((v){


          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>SmsCode()
          ),);
       // }else{
         // Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        //}
      });

    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("formulaire d'authentification"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              onChanged:loginBloc.phoneEvent.add,
              onSubmitted:(String value) =>loginBloc.onClickPhone,
              maxLength: 13,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Phone number"),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: navigateTOnext,

              child: Text("verifier"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );


  }
```

Comment: Nice example.
This line 
              `builder: (BuildContext context) =>SmsCode()` in ui is not clear. Can you please clarify what SmsCode() method is doing.

Comment: builder: (BuildContext context) =>SmsCode() it's just an other UI Screen witch wait for SMS send to the phone  number.